Wezterm start FAILURE -- queue destroyed, proxies attached
I was starting to find out about Wezterm this week.  Then it started failing to run.  It is a mystery, there is a Plasma window frame for Wezterm on the task bar -- nothing else.  Once earlier I had a config error and an editor window opened with a diagnostic.  I loved that!  This problem, the app is silent.  I have installed the Flatpak for Wezterm.
When I run from bash I see a warning message:
$ wezterm start
warning: queue 0x557903e2d6d0 destroyed while proxies still attached:
  wl_registry@31 still attached
warning: queue 0x557904dfe0f0 destroyed while proxies still attached:
  wl_registry@36 still attached
MESA: error: CreateSwapchainKHR failed with VK_ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED
MESA: error: zink: could not create swapchain

... and just has there with an icon on the task bar, viz.:

A couple of things came to mind that this might be some left-over resource after a previous instance was terminated.  Do you know where I'd need to go to clean-up old context, etc?  Is this something to do with flatpak?
Another question came to mind.  Is/are if there is a background task/process running for one (or more) of those things mentioned: proxies, registry or queue-s.
I am looking for options for logs and to see what else is happening.   I expect I'll have to set-up a build to see what's happening in real-life with the app start-up.

Context

Kubuntu
Plasma / Wayland
Flatpak -- org.wezfurlong.wezterm

version is: wezterm 20240203-110809-5046fc22



Thoughts and suggestions welcome.

small update
When I built from source and ran Wezterm start it all came good, on same environment.  Seems like something relating to the build in Flatpak perhaps.

$ cargo build --release`
    Finished `release` profile [optimized] target(s) in 0.65s
$ ./target/release/wezterm --version
wezterm 20240508-081413-d2fa4e98
$ ./target/release/wezterm  start

